# django rest framework choosing between two possible views for hyperlinked field

Tags: django-rest-framework

So I have two different API views on to User, one that superusers can use, and one that normal users can use.

At the moment, the problem is that my hyperlinks are going to auth_users view by default, instead of to the users view.

i.e.

```
'url': 'localhost:8000/auth_users/5/'
```

instead of

```
'url': 'localhost:8000/users/5/'
```

Here are extracts from the relevant files...

*** URLS ***

router =

```
routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'auth_users', UserAPI.AdminUserViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^users/?$', UserAPI.CreateOrList.as_view(), name='users'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/?$', UserAPI.RetrieveUpdateOrDestroy.as_view()),
    ...
)
```

*** serializer ***

```
class basic_user_serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='users')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'email', 'username']
```

*** views ***

```
class CreateOrList(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    List all users, or create a new one.
    """
    serializer_class = create_user_serializer


class RetrieveUpdateOrDestroy(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = create_user_serializer
```

I've had a look at the docs (linked below) but am not sure if this is explained...
http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#hyperlinkedidentityfield

Anyone know how to fix it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I fixed it.

I got rid of the auth_user view to see what would happen, and it threw an error page saying it couldn't find 'user-detail'.

I then changed the name of the users view to 'user-detail', re-enabled the auth_user view, and it works properly now.

No idea why, though - didn't I tell it to use 'users' instead of 'user-detail'??